# Grep fixed word and end of line character

Tags: regex, bash, grep, eof

I'm writing a bash script and I would like to print all lines containing a word, but only if it is at the end of a line. So given a file like this:

```
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  ./12/2.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  ./12/1
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  ./12/1.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  ./1
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  ./11.txt
```

and the given word equal to "./1" I would like to print only the line:

```
717c41ff4049b0e8cbdc7ec7e49ad021  ./1
```

I'd simply use grep, with "$" anchor added at the end, for that but my problem is that the words may contain dots so I need to have the `-F` option, but then I am unsure how to secure that the printed lines contain the word at the end of the line, as I can't use line anchors.

Edit:
The word is passed as a variable not a fixed string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `awk` if your definition of word means white-space separated as given in sample input

```
$ awk '$NF == "./1"' ip.txt 
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  ./1
```

This will print only those lines whose last field is exactly equal to string `./1`

No need to worry about escaping regex meta characters if the search word changes

To pass shell variable:

```
$ s='./1'
$ awk -v word="$s" '$NF == word' ip.txt 
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  ./1
```

See also [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)

Comment: Thanks @Sundeep, what if the word is passed as a variable? How do I use awk then?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` with this pattern:

```
grep '\./1$' file

d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  ./1
```

`\./1$` will match `./1` only at the end of line due to anchor `$`.

---

Based on comment below, if you want to pass search term using a variable:

```
s='./1'

awk -v s="$s" 'index($0, s) + length(s) -1 == length()' file

d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  ./1
```

**This will also work when search term is not separated by whitespaces**

Comment: The problem is that the value is passed as a variable, so I can't escape the dot character this way.

Comment: ok check my updated `awk` command to be used with a variable.

Answer (score -1):

If the name you want to search for contains `.` you can escape them.  e.g

```
bash-3.2$ NAME="./1"
bash-3.2$ grep "$(sed -e 's/[.]/[.]/g' <<< "$NAME")$" file
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  ./1
```

Comment: I believe this answers the OP's question and offers a suggestion as to how the OP can transform the word they are searching for into an argument they can pass to `grep`.  Anyone care to point out what's wrong with this answer?  What did I miss?

Comment: When you want literal strings, use literal strings, don't try to disable all possible regexp metacharacters to try to make your regexp behave as if it were a string.